# Test for Open Connections to a Client From a REST Service Using Java and JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am not as familiar with web services and I'm having a hard time finding information about a question regarding the way clients interact with a RESTful web service.

I've implemented a REST web interface to interact with clients using Java and the Jersey JAX-RS library, however I need to limit the number of connected clients to 6. If I have 6 clients connected and a 7th tries to connect, I need to know if one of the other 6 has disconnected at some point so I can give the new client a connection. Is there a simple way to tell on the server side if a client is still connected? Do clients maintain connection in a REST web service after they complete a request to the server? Normally the clients I'm dealing with make HTTP POST and GET requests to the server at least one a second.

The only thing I can think of would be to ping each connected client and wait for a response in the event of another client trying to connect. If one ping times out then I could replace that client with the new one. But I'm not really sure how that would impact server performance. If anyone has any input on a way too accomplish this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have such odd requirement? What's your real issue?

Comment: My requirement is to only allow 6 concurrent connections to the server due to performance concerns. It may be odd, but the issue is connection management.

Comment: Again: why do you have such odd requirement? Let the server handle this, not you. Also, a connection should be released when the server provides a response for a client. Or do you mean about database connections?

Comment: It's just a requirement for the design of this particular system. I have data stored on the server that is specific to the client it came from so I need to know what clients are still making calls to the server to utilize that data, and which are not so I can give priority to other clients trying to connect.

Comment: I guess you should rephrase all the question with this as the main feature, otherwise the question is really odd. And again, this is part of the server app more than the implementation of your services.

Comment: Okay that's fine but how does the server handle that exactly?

Comment: It will depend on the application server you use. Do some research on how to control how many connections your app server can allow and if you can change that behavior.

Comment: But the issue still persists that even with the server managing the number of concurrent connections, I need to know exactly which client disconnected, not just that a connection is available for use.

Comment: This is a responsability of the web server so it would be better if you say witch one are you using. And clients can maintain connection or not, it is up to the server configuration (keep-alive).

Comment: Tomcat 7. Connections are configured to be kept alive. I understand the server will manage connections based on its configuration, but will it notify me of the exact client that disconnected, or will it just allow a new connection from a new client if another client drops off? If no, what is the best way to figure out which exact client dropped off?